# Usage of && to pass same value to variable in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, variables, select, oracle11g

I have below script where I have to pass same OWNER and TABLE_NAME values twice times. Instead 
I am trying use '&&' like mentioned at https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:818426831007

But wondering why it is not working for below query

```
SELECT table_name, round (SUM(bytes)/1024/1024/1024, 2) AS "Total Size"
FROM (SELECT s.segment_name AS table_name, s.bytes
FROM dba_SEGMENTS s
          WHERE s.segment_name IN
                   ('&&table_name')
                    and s.owner='&&owner'
UNION
         SELECT l.table_name AS table_name, s.bytes
           FROM dba_SEGMENTS s, dba_lobs l
          WHERE s.segment_name = l.segment_name AND l.owner = '&owner'
                AND l.table_name IN
                       ('&table_name'))
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an error? What is it? This is a named substitution variable; are you expecting to have to input the owner string manually?

Comment: When I run the query, it is not even prompting to enter value for owner and table_name. Instead it is taking null values and returning no rows selected.

Comment: Where and how are you running this? SQL*Plus and SQL Developer prompt by default; if you're using one of those what does `show define` report? I believe other clients like Toad prompt for substitution variables too. So which client are you using? Or.. have you run it already, been prompted but just hit return? If you you can `undefine owner` before running it again.

Comment: It is working. I am using SQL*PLUS. I had to restart my session cause I already passed some values to these variables when I am working around with the script. Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: OK, so what does `show define` say? And are you running it in a new session?

Comment: SQL> show define
define "&" (hex 26)
and yes I ran it in a new session

Answer (score 0):

It is working. I am using SQL*PLUS. I had to restart my session cause I already passed some values to these variables when I was working around with the script. Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: You could also have done `undefine owner` and `undefine table_name`.